# Name of statistical animated visualization

Tags: data-visualization, terminology, graphical-model

What is the name of the kind of animatrd graph that show a development over a period of time - and the vertical bars change length and order.

Fx country on y-axis, no of COVID-19 cases on x-axis, and then like a stop motion movie, the bars expand and change order (over a period of one year fx)

Answer (score 0):

There are [many names](https://visme.co/blog/types-of-graphs/) for just what you need for instance:

- trellis bar graphs
- stacked bar graphs

Comment: This does not address animation, although I don't have an answer other than e.g.  animated stacked bar graph.

Comment: yeah @NickCox I guess animated just means convert multiple of these to an animated gif or so.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's any special name for these. I would just refer to such graphs as **animated X**, where X = bar chart/scatterplot/etc.

It's worth specifying that the animation communicates changes over time, but people would likely assume this anyway because that's the most common use for animation in figures.